# How can I come up with creating an algorithm which simulates a real time situation

Tags: algorithm, computation-theory

I'm good at algorithms but not as good as converting real-time problems and learning them throughly to make it as an algorithm. I would like to know if there is any book/paper that teaches or makes you demystify the situation and formulate it as an algorithm. (Its much like training your mental ability to break the situation and comeup with algorithm in a crisp.)

Showing some of the ways to approach these kinda problems. and any easy learning links/material would help me a lot.

**Note:** I know SO doesnt allow to ask for the opinion or something vague (I dont mind my Q being downgraded). But I am asking some concrete problem and hope can get some nice info from some of the great minds here.

Comment: I for one don't understand what you're asking. Can you give an example of an existing "algorithm which simulates a real time situation"?

Comment: My guess is that [programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) is better platform for this question. Could be wrong though :|

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, I meant to say expressing a realtime situation in terms of an Algorithm.

Comment: @uDaY: Avoid using the term real time here, since it is usually understood in the context of computing as [Real time computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing), which is different from what you are after.

Comment: @amit, ok. I should have said **day-day** events (or) **event driven scenarios.** :D

Comment: I wanted to answer. But the question is closed. I think this is an interesting question and I am waiting for better answers too. Dont know why it is closed.

Comment: @amit I do think you're right about this belonging on the programmers.SE site. (to uDaY) I think the term you're looking for is "real-world".

Answer (score 1):

The word that fits better as a direct answer is "experience". There exists no magical formula to convert a real time problem into some algorithms that solve it. As an analogy, there exist no predefined patterns on how to solve a mathematical problem. It is a mind's task to express the solution, based on some fundamental knowledge and on experience that is accumulated though constant learning.